# Android Studio Error on Mac

Tags: android, android-studio

Just installed Android Studio 0.2.2 on my mac with osx 10.8.4 and opend new project tried to compile it and got this:`Gradle: Execution failed for task ':MyApplication:dexDebug'.

> Failed to run command:
>       /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/build-tools/18.0.0/dx --dex --output /Users/shimon_wi/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplicationProject/MyApplication/build/libs/MyApplication-debug.dex /Users/shimon_wi/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplicationProject/MyApplication/build/classes/debug /Users/shimon_wi/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplicationProject/MyApplication/build/dependency-cache/debug /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/13.0.0/support-v4-13.0.0.jar
>     Error Code:
>       1
>     Output:
>       /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/build-tools/18.0.0/dx: line 31: dirname: No such file or directory
>       /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/build-tools/18.0.0/dx: line 34: basename: No such file or directory

```
/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/build-tools/18.0.0/dx: line 48: dirname: No such file or directory
/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/build-tools/18.0.0/dx: line 52: basename: No such file or directory`
```

does any one know how to overcome this?

Comment: Did you find solutin? Same problem here…

Comment: No and nobody seems to know, did you found anything?

Comment: Yes, but I reorganised much. Moved some child libraries to compile dependencies and so on. Check SDK manager and download support repositories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hit same issue today with android studio 0.4.2 and sdk version 20131030.

Seems like "dx" script does not have correctly set PATH (or maybe this applies only when invoked from Android Studio, who knows..). I was able to get it working by adding

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/:/bin/
```

to

```
sdk/build-tools/android-4.4/dx
```

(first line after comments block). Not saying this is ideal solution, but it does not seem to be configurable in Android Studio and it does not introduce any risk to proper function of SDK. And might have to do this again when SDK is updated/reinstalled.

Comment: This solved my issue which had the slight variant, `dirname: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you what causes this problem, but I managed to solve it for me. Hopefully you have the same issue as me: What happened was that I enabled the system firewall for OS X.  By mistake I banned java. After this the problem appeared. Restarting the terminal and re-enabling java fixed the problem (System preferences --> Security & Privacy --> Firewall --> Firewall options).

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was the $ PATH in OS X 10.9.4.

'dirname' and 'basename' commands are in the /usr/bin usually and '/usr/bin' is included in your $PATH.
But I modify the /etc/launchd.conf file incorrectly.
So /usr/bin is not included in $PATH.

Perhaps this problem will occur only in the IDE and to be fine in the terminal.
Please check your $PATH value.